# Interpolate a variable in a shell command run by Ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to run Ansible task similar to this one:

```
---
- name: symlink the nodejs executable to node
  command: ln -sf "$(which nodejs)" /usr/bin/node
  sudo: True
```

I found that the part `"$(which nodejs)"` would not be interpolated to string, but taken literalle - consequently, creating a malformed symlink.

How can I interpolate this part to a proper string with Ansible command module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

I was probably to eager to ask first rather than try to find solution myself. Here is one solution:

```
---
- name: Find path to nodejs
  command: which nodejs
  register: nodejs_path

- name: symlink the nodejs executable to node
  command: "ln -sf {{ item }} /usr/bin/node"
  sudo: True
  with_items: nodejs_path.stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

@luqo33

Interpolating a shell variable like saying `$hostname`, the best module to use for that purpose is `shell module` instead of `command module` and I you need more flexibility of bash, the use args executable as bash. A quick task for that would be as follows:

```
    - name: symlink the nodejs executable to node
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd:  ln -sf "$(which java)" /usr/bin/node
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
```